# Google Map API not working in wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am creating wordpress plugin for MAP location.

Inside plugin code I have used following code.

```
 function wpyog_press_scripts() {   
   // Load Google Maps API. Make sure to add the callback and add custom-scripts dependency
   wp_register_script('wpyog-google-maps', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBDpN1kFL3vTBAjWQySIVsCMdrzDTRdTL0&callback=initMap', array(), 
  '1.0', 
  true 
   );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpyog_press_scripts' );

add_shortcode( 'wpyog_map_locator_frontend', 'wpyog_map_locator_frontend' );
function wpyog_map_locator_frontend(){
    global $wpdb,$content;  
    ob_start(); 
    wp_enqueue_script('wpyog-google-maps'); ?>
    <script>
    var map;
    var markers = [];
    var infoWindow;
    var locationSelect;

    function initMap() {
       var uk_country = {lat: 51.509865, lng: -0.118092};
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  center: uk_country,
   zoom: 6,
mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU}
   });
   infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
}

<?php 
   $includeFile = WPYog_MAP_LOCATOR_DIR.'views/wpyog_map_locator_frontend.php';
   include( $includeFile );
    return ob_get_clean();
  }
```

Inside wpyog_map_locator_frontend.php file

```
 <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 90%;"></div>
```

But my Map is not showing. When I check in console it return 304 status code

Answer (score 0):

use ::
add_action('wp_footer', 'wpyog_press_scripts');
instead of
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpyog_press_scripts' );

if not work then 
-> remove "&callback=initMap" from script line.
-> add your script in header.
-> call initMap function on shortcode area after shortcode data loaded.

Comment: After putting in header it will shows ReferenceError: google is not defined this error